# How can I make light that changes its color with path length?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I want to create a light source whose light colour will change with ray length.

Example:

`(light src)______________
        |    \           \_______
        |      \                 \______
        |(red)   \ (green)              \(blue)
(plane)_______________________________________________________________`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

The node setup for the lamp:

[image]

- Ray length as input
- A power for tuning the value
- HSV node which shifts the input color depending on the ray length
- All connected to the color socket of the lamp

The plane which receives the light is just a simple diffuse shader.

An alternative configuration:

[image]

Comment: thanks for comprehensive answer, but i wonder why do i need a separate object to get ray length information and not just create some node setup for a light source?

Comment: Well... in fact, you can !! Sorry, my answer was bad : I rewrite all that !

Comment: @FanciestBanana, I have to say your question above helped me to understand the answer : )...